# Replace service registration in ASP.NET Core built-in DI container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let us consider a service registration in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IFoo, FooA>();
}
```

Is it possible to change `IFoo` registration to `FooB` after `AddTransient` has been called? It can be helpful for testing purposes (for example, in `TestStartup` subclass) or if our access to codebase is limited.

If we register another `IFoo` implementation:

```
services.AddTransient<IFoo, FooA>();
services.AddTransient<IFoo, FooB>();
```

Then `GetService<IFoo>` returns `FooB` instead of `FooA`:

```
IFoo service = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IFoo>();
Assert.True(service is FooB);
```

However, `GetServices<IFoo>` successfully returns both implementations (and the same for `GetService<IEnumerable<IFoo>>`):

```
var list = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetServices<IFoo>().ToList();
Assert.Equal(2, list.Count);
```

There is `Remove(ServiceDescriptor)` method in `IServiceCollection` contract. What should I do with `ServiceDescriptor` to modify a service registration?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This is simple using the [`Replace(IServiceCollection, ServiceDescriptor)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.replace) method from the [`ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_Extensions_ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions) class.

```
// IFoo -> FooA
services.AddTransient<IFoo, FooA>();

// Replace
// IFoo -> FooB
var descriptor =
    new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(IFoo),
        typeof(FooB),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.Replace(descriptor);
```

See also:

- [ServiceDescriptor constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor#constructors)

Comment: `Replace` internally calls the same `Add` and `Remove` methods which I considered. It is a good addition anyway, thanks.

Comment: Another way (in less lines, but using the same methods); `services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IFoo, FooB>());`

Comment: Would it be a good practice to do this but with a singleton?

Comment: @Vesper There may be use cases when you need to replace a singleton.

Comment: @Vesper certainly, very useful in test scenarios (e.g. you have a singleton logger and you want to test some logs are being written)

Comment: If you want a singleton:

```services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IFoo>(_ => yourInstance));```

Answer (score 69):

It is easy to override ASP.NET Core DI functionality if you know two simple things:

#### 1. [`ServiceCollection`](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollection.cs) is just a wrapper on top of `List<ServiceDescriptor>`:

```
    public class ServiceCollection : IServiceCollection
    {
        private List<ServiceDescriptor> _descriptors = new List<ServiceDescriptor>();
    }
```

#### 2.  When a service is registered, a new descriptor is [added to list](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs):

```
    private static IServiceCollection Add(
        IServiceCollection collection,
        Type serviceType,
        Type implementationType,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    {
        var descriptor = new ServiceDescriptor(serviceType, implementationType, lifetime);
        collection.Add(descriptor);
        return collection;
    }
```

Therefore, it is possible to add/remove descriptors to/from this list to replace the registration:

```
IFoo service = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IFoo>();
Assert.True(service is FooA);

var descriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IFoo));
Assert.NotNull(descriptor);
services.Remove(descriptor);

service = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IFoo>();
Assert.Null(service);
```

We finish with `Replace<TService, TImplementation>` extention method:

```
services.Replace<IFoo, FooB>(ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Its implementation:

```
public static IServiceCollection Replace<TService, TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    where TService : class
    where TImplementation : class, TService
{
    var descriptorToRemove = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(TService));

    services.Remove(descriptorToRemove);

    var descriptorToAdd = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TService), typeof(TImplementation), lifetime);

    services.Add(descriptorToAdd);

    return services;
}
```

Comment: How can we reflect the change of `ServiceCollection` to `IServiceProvider`?

Comment: How can i use this in a controller? I mean how can I replace a service from a controller?

Comment: @Hatef you can't do it from a controller, it should be done from `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: And the only proper way to modify `ServiceCollection` is to do it before the container is built, i.e. before object implementing `IServiceProvider`  is created.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add on @ilya-chumakov 's great answer, here is the same method but with support for implementation factories

```
public static IServiceCollection Replace<TService>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Func<IServiceProvider, TService> implementationFactory,
    ServiceLifetime lifetime)
    where TService : class
{
    var descriptorToRemove = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(TService));

    services.Remove(descriptorToRemove);

    var descriptorToAdd = new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TService), implementationFactory, lifetime);

    services.Add(descriptorToAdd);

    return services;
}
```

in case we want to use it with a factory that instantiates the service like the following sample:

```
var serviceProvider = 
  new ServiceCollection()
    .Replace<IMyService>(sp => new MyService(), ServiceLifetime.Singleton)
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Comment: I tried to use your code in controller. but it doesn't work. do I missed something?

Comment: If you provide more details about what's not working maybe I can help. But this code works fine.

Answer (score 7):

In the latest version of .net core(net5.0), this is how it should be.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

services.Replace<IFoo, FooB>(ServiceLifetime.Transient); // Or ServiceLifetime.Singleton
```

Or try this one.

```
services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IFoo, FooB>());
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work. The second one works.

Answer (score 3):

I replace the repository in my Test Fixture WebApplicationFactory using

```
    public static WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> WithRepository<TEntryPoint>(
        this WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> webApplicationFactory,
        IStoreRepository storeRespository)
        where TEntryPoint : class
    {
        return webApplicationFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => builder.ConfigureTestServices(
               services =>
               {
                   services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped(p => storeRespository));
               }));
    }
```

And use it in the test as

```
var respository = new ListRepository();
var client = _factory
    .WithRepository(respository)
    .CreateClient();
```

If the services has multiple registrations, then you have to remove first. Replace is not removing all the instances.

```
services.RemoveAll(typeof(IStoreRepository));
```

Comment: This `builder.ConfigureTestServices()` helps me with my unit testing projects, thanks.